# OLEDB Connection fails with Invalid Path

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

Using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogPicker)` to select a file to make an OLEDB connection in Excel VBA.
The full filename returned (dummied-up to protect the guilty) is: D:\MyUserName\Documents\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\My Filename.csv

`ConnectionString` is:
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MyUserName\Documents\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\My Filename.csv;Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited';

`Connection.Open ConnectionString` fails, reporting the path is not valid. I can copy/paste the filename part of `ConnectionString` (less the file name) into the address bar of File Explorer and it successfully goes to the folder.

Putting the filename part of `ConnectionString` (including the filename) into the address bar opens the file.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The folder is a database, the files are the tables.

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConn As String, SQL As String

    Const FOLDER = "D:\MyUserName\Documents\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\"
    Const TABLE = "My Filename.csv"

    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & FOLDER & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited';"

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & TABLE & "]"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
        .Open sConn
        Set rs = .Execute(SQL)
        Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Close
    End With
    MsgBox "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a whirl and Give an upvote and check off as the answer once I get it working